# BlackBerry default app for Epub file type

Tags: blackberry, epub

I'm developing an Epub reader on BlackBerry java platform, and I'd like to know if there is a possible way to register my application as the default reader for Epub files, like if a clicked on an attached Epub file within an email, or a link to that file in browser, or even if I clicked on it while browsing all files locally, am I going so far with this? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Content Handler APIs, which allow you to register an app to handle files of a particular extension and content type (e.g. `.epub` and type `application/epub+zip`).

See [this BlackBerry reference document for more information](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/23567/Integration_handling_content_1375916_11.jsp)

If you install the full SDK, you should also find the **CHAPIdemo** sample code under `samples/com/rim/samples/device/chapidemo`.